# Why is template argument deduction/substitution failing?

Tags: c++, templates

This has been driving me crazy. I am experimenting with converting types to bytes and back, which I had working. As I built functions around my approach, I was getting template deduction errors, but I cannot see any reason why it should be happening. Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
uint8_t *to_bytes(T &val) {
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&val);
};

template<typename T>
T *from_bytes(uint8_t *bytes) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(bytes);
};

int main() {
    double a = 10.4;
    uint8_t *bytevals = to_bytes(a);

    // "Send" the data out and receive it into an array
    uint8_t bytes_rx[sizeof(a)];
    for (int byt_ndx = 0; byt_ndx < sizeof(a); ++byt_ndx) {
        bytes_rx[byt_ndx] = bytevals[byt_ndx];
    }

    double *thing_back;
    thing_back = from_bytes(&bytes_rx[0]);

    cout << *thing_back;
}
```

And the error when I build:

```
C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\CodingPractice\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\CodingPractice\main.cpp:31:41: error: no matching function for call to 'from_bytes(uint8_t*)'
     thing_back = from_bytes(&bytes_rx[0]);
                                         ^
C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\CodingPractice\main.cpp:14:4: note: candidate: template<class T> T* from_bytes(uint8_t*)
 T *from_bytes(uint8_t *bytes) {
    ^
C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\CodingPractice\main.cpp:14:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\CodingPractice\main.cpp:31:41: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
     thing_back = from_bytes(&bytes_rx[0]);
```

It's worth mentioning if I replace the function calls directly with the code in the functions, everything works well.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parameter `T` is not used in the arguments to the function. Hence, `T` cannot be deduced from the arguments used to call it.

You need to be explicit about the template parameter.

```
thing_back = from_bytes<double>(&bytes_rx[0]);
```

If you are opposed to using the template parameter explicitly, you can use a dummy argument to the function.

```
template<typename T>
T *from_bytes(uint8_t *bytes, T* dummy) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(bytes);
};
```

and use it as:

```
thing_back = from_bytes(&bytes_rx[0], things_back);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was thinking that setting `double *thing_back` to the value returned from `from_bytes(&bytes_rx[0])` would be enough to inform the template. How come it cannot? I can see how that approach may not be flexible but I'm not confident of a reason.

Comment: @LordGonk, the type of the object to which the return value of a function is assigned is never used to deduce which function gets called. That's true for not only function templates but also ordinary functions -- member functions as well as non-member functions.